# Web Api returns an error has occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I wrote an api to get some objects in json format. It get values in Linq command and goes to the return Method. But does not return what I expect.

```
values return ({"Message": "An error has occurred."})
```

I Searched a lot but did not find anything yet.

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetOrdersOfPostman(string postmanId)
    {
        try
        {
            var postmanCustomersModel = new List<PostmanCustomerModel>();
            var id = Convert.ToInt64(postmanId);

            var orderStatus = (byte) OrderStatus.DeliverToPostman;
            var orders = _orderRepository.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.PostmanId == id && x.OrderStatus==orderStatus &&
                         x.SellerCustomerId > 0).ToList();

            return Ok(orders);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could try debugging yourself: set a breakpoint at the start of your controller body and step through the code to find out what goes wrong...

Comment: I set Breakpoint code work correctly but return error .

Comment: Yeah..try to debug and you can find it in InnerException (ex.InnerException)

Comment: Did you browsed the method's URL in browser?? If yes then what is the output?

Comment: Did you set the right  [ResponseType(...)] attribute, and are your orders serializable?

Comment: I tested it in localhost , with postman , it go on return (orders) line  , but return that strange message .

Comment: I do not know on serializable give me a suitble link please . thanks Johan Donne

Comment: Okay do you have latest version of Newtonsoft.Json in your api?

Answer (score 3):

there are two methods for doing that.

1. Include [`Json` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and then return custom json object. Just pass the your list of `orders` in Json and return.

`return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new jTableResponse(result), Formatting.None);`

OR

`return Json(yourobject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

2. Another choice is to make your own response model and then return it as Json object using Json library.

Below is the complete example.

```
using System; 
namespace MyProject.Api_Models
{
    public class ApiResponse
    {
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public Object Data { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and it is used as:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetGroupFriendsLists(int groupid)
{
    var grp = db.Groups.Where(k => k.GroupId == groupid).Any();
    if (!grp)
    {
        return Json(new ApiResponse
        {
            Message = "Invalid group inforamtion.",
            Status = false
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    var lists = db.Groups.Where(k => k.GroupId == groupid).Select(k => k.SharedLists).FirstOrDefault().Where(k => k.ListType == SharedListTypes.Friends && (k.ExpiryDate == null || k.ExpiryDate.Value.Date > DateTime.Now.Date)).Select(
        k =>
        new
        {
            k.CreatorId,
            ExpiryDate = HelperFunctions.DateTimeFormattedString(k.ExpiryDate),
            k.ListId,
            k.ListName,
            k.ListType,
            TimeStamp = HelperFunctions.DateTimeFormattedString(k.TimeStamp),
            ItemsCount = k.ListItems.Count
        }).ToList();
    if (lists.Count <= 0)
    {
        return Json(new ApiResponse
        {
            Status = false,
            Message = "No friends lists in this group."
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(new ApiResponse
    {
        Status = true,
        Message = "We found the friends shared lists of this group.",
        Data = lists
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You can test it out.

Comment: Since it is a web api, why do we need to use Json() here.  Why not Ok()

Comment: yes, it can be used, but i think, it's better for new comers to manipulate and get full control over their own custom response.

Comment: @PowerStar this is a simple example, not to complex things with all necessary boundry conditions, for getting start for first API.

Comment: In point of view, your answer seems to be complex.  .net already provides many out of the box features.  So we need to use that instead of re-inventing.

Comment: this line really disappointed me "return Json(yourobject)".  If you edit then I will do upvote.

Comment: that's actually, Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior).
btw, i removed it. you can now upvote.

Comment: can i add that line with parameter? like i said, I missed the parameter.... was my mistake.